# Intellij idea Sonarlint icon can not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarlint

I'm using intellij idea (2017.3.5) sonarlint and sonarqube are the last version. 
When I use sonarlint then I take an exception as follows :

```
ERROR - tellij.openapi.util.IconLoader - Icon cannot be found in '/images/severity/mınor12.png', aClass='class icons.SonarLintIcons' 
java.lang.Throwable: Icon cannot be found in '/images/severity/mınor12.png', aClass='class icons.SonarLintIcons'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/openapi/util/IconLoader.getIcon must not return null
```

Comment: This is a bug in the SonarLint plugin. Please report it to the plugin developers.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the SonarLint plugin and install the compatible one?

Comment: yes I did, but did not change(uninstall latest version  then install other versions(3.5 ..2.4... )